# Deploying Django application on Webfaction

Tags: python, django, deployment, web-deployment, webfaction

This is the first time I am trying to deploy my django project (myproject) on Webfaction.

My project dir-structure is as follows:

1. In webapps/django: myproject.wsgi, myproject
2. settings.py is at myproject/src/myproject/

Under such circumstances, how should I define `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in myproject.wsgi?

For the default installation by webfaction, it is defined as `myproject.settings`. Should I be defining `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` as `myproject.src.myproject.settings`?

Comment: placing wsgi file at myproject/src and defining DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to 'myproject.settings' did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

When you setup a Django project on webfaction, you get a file structure like so:

```
~ (your home directory)
    +webapps
        +some_project_name
            +myproject
                -standard django files
                -settings.py
                -app_directory
            +apache2
                +bin
                    -start
                    -stop
                    -restart
                -other dirs
            -bin
            -lib
            -myproject.wsgi
        -some_project2
        -symlink_to_static_files
```

If you are building your project under "myproject", you should not have to modify the wsgi file to get started- just change to the apache2/bin directory and run ./start and you're good to go!
If you change the wsgi file you'll need to run ./stop then ./start to activate the changes.

If the path you listed isn't working, it may be worth trying to create a generic django project and just puaste your project right over 'myproject'

Answer (score -1):

It seems like your service provider has already given you some helpful instructions:
http://docs.webfaction.com/software/django/getting-started.html

Comment: All doc of webfaction is too old... you cannot recommanded someone to go there.